# Previous Posts Link and Next Posts Link Show All The Same Articles?

Tags: loop, navigation

I just fixed the problem of my featured posts section displaying on every index page instead of just the first one. This, of course, created a brand new problem. The first page looks fine; my featured posts are all where they should be and the loop below doesn't include any repeat posts. But then I click on "older entries" at the bottom of the page and page two contains the first eight posts from the loop. Page three contains the same eight posts, as do pages four, five, six, and presumably all of them.

[Here's page two](http://inkandpixelclub.com/page/2/), where the problem starts. What do I need to add or take out in order to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I think I have an idea of where the problem is, but not how to fix it. Everything seems to work fine until I add in the query_posts to offset the main loop by 4, since those posts are displayed up in the feature area. It seems that when I go to page two and beyond, every page is starting from that offset of four instead of continuing on to display the next batch of posts. If I take out the query, it works fine, except for the fact that I have duplicate posts in the loop.

Comment: Hi, did you figur out how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

How many calls to query_posts() are you making? If you're making more than one, then you need to replace one of them with a call to WP_Query, or get_posts() - and you need to call wp_reset_query() between the Loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead (more native, closer to core): `get_adjacent_post()` - [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) ... for a more indepth look at how it works, look at my repo [@github](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Easy-Pagination-Deamon)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks like it would be useful for finding the next single post on a single post page. I need something to fix the links on my main index page so they'll stop returning the same eight posts.

Comment: Download the plugin from the repo and add the template tag below or above (outside) your loop-code. You'll see it working, like described in the readme.textile file in the repo (index page). On single post pages you need to include it inside the loop and no first/last will work there.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I put in the template tag on the index page, but I'm only getting a fatal error message saying it's an undefined function.

Comment: I decided that the easiest thing would be to just set up a new category for the other posts I wanted the main loop to skip and add an additional line of code to have it skip that category. I wanted to avoid adding a new category, but everything else I tried was just breaking my site more and more. I appreciate the help regardless.

Comment: undefined function? Have you added the plugin to your plugin folder?

Comment: About an hour after I tried it out, I realized that the issue was likely that I put the plugin in my theme folder instead of plugins. Completely my dumb mistake: I'm self taugh in web design and stressed out from the issues with the site. I think I'm going to give it a rest for now and try again tomorrow when I'm more refreshed. Like I said, I've worked out a reasonable fix for the issue, but now the loop is refusing to show a couple of posts, so I will probably try your plugin again and see if it fixes this new problem.

Comment: @InkAndPixelClub: You can also put it somewhere in your themes folder, but you'll have to `require STYLESHEETPATH.'/your_folder_for_pagination/pagination_deamon.php` and then use it like this (functions.php) `$my_pagination = new PaginationDeamon( $range = 9 );` and somewhere in your theme: `echo $my_pagination;`. `$range` could be any number and `$mypagination` any name. I hope it's not broken, because i completely screwed my local setup and repos yesterday... Pls just report back. Upvoting is also appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. I moved the files and the whole folder into my plugins folder, but I'm still getting the same error message. It's probably something I'm missing, as my coding skills are not great.

Answer (score -1):

Too less space in a comment: Try the following in your `functions.php` file (of your theme). Plugin must be active and within it's own folder inside `/root/wp-content/plugins/$folder`. You have to specify the name of your plugin folder inside the function

```
    function check_deamon_class() {
        // check if plugin is active
        // ENTER NAME OF FOLDER HERE:
        $folder = 'example_easy_pagination_deamon'; // Enter the name of the folder in which you got the plugin files here
        $plugin_info = 'The pagination deamon plugin is';
        $plugin_info .= !is_plugin_active( $folder ) ? ' not active.' : ' active.'; 
        // check if the class can be loaded
        $class_info = '<br />';
        $class_info .= 'The deamon class';
        $class_info .= !class_exists('PaginationDeamon') ? ' was not found.' : ' was found.';
        $deamon = new oxoPaginationDeamon;
        $range = 5;
        $deamon_test = $deamon->links( $range );
        $info = '<div style="position: absolute; display: block; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #000; color: #fff; top: 0; left: 0;"><p>'.$plugin_info.$class_info.'</p><br />'.$deamon_test.'</div>';
        return print $info;
    }
    if ( function_exists('wp_footer') ) {   
      add_action( 'wp_footer', 'check_deamon_class' ); 
    } 
    else { 
      echo '<div style="position: absolute; display: block; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #000; color: #fff; top: 0; left: 0;"><p>Your Theme has no "wp_footer()" hook to attach the test.</p></div>';
    }
```

Tell me what note you receive within a black box with white text in the upper left of your page.